# I want to Use grep to search /etc/services

Tags: grep

How can I use grep to search `/etc/services` and output only the lines for services whose names end with an `s` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cut -f1 /etc/services | grep -v '^#' | grep 's$'
```

or

```
cut -f1 /etc/services | grep '^[^#].*s$'
```

## Explanation

1. The file `/etc/services` contains multiple columns while the name of the service is the first one. To print the first column of a file that uses tabs (`\t`), use `cut -f1` (`f` stands for **f**ield).
2. There are also comments in the file which start with a `#` symbol. The command `grep -v '^#'` filters them out.

   - `-v` prints lines *not* containing the pattern,
   - `^` means the beginning of the line.
3. Now we get the list of services which can be simply filtered using `grep 's$'`.

   - `$` means the end of the line.

## Alternatives

- The two `grep` calls can be combined into one: `grep '^[^#].*s$'`. This regular expression looks for the lines fulfilling all of the following rules:

  - not beginning with `#` (to be more exact: beginning (`^`) with a character not equal to `#` (`[^#]`)
  - followed by an unspecified number of any characters (`.*`) and
  - having an `s` right before the end of the line (`$`).
- The commands `sed` or `awk` could get the job done, too.

## Dealing with duplicates

You might find that the service names are listed multiple times since they use multiple ports. (This information is covered by the second column which we’ve filtered out.) There is a command to print every item once and in alphabetical order at the same time: `sort --unique`.
Simply pipe the output of the previous command to `sort`:

```
cut -f1 /etc/services | grep '^[^#].*s$' | sort --unique
```

## See also

- [`man grep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)
- [`man cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)
- [`man sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer was very clear and well written. It explained exactly what I needed .Truly Appreciate your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

`grep "s$" /etc/services` is the answer.

You find the answer by reading the manual, [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/grep.1.html) in a terminal, or searching for it on the net.